# How to update mysql database using a submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

How do you update mysql database when i click on the update function. The fields that i want to update are in the textfield that i have created.

```
<script>

     function yourfunction() 
     {
         document.getElementById("name").readOnly = true;
         document.getElementById("number").readOnly = true;
         document.getElementById("status").readOnly = true;
         document.getElementById("expertise").readOnly = true;
         document.getElementById("remark").readOnly = true;

     }

    window.onload = yourfunction;

    function myfunction()
    {
        document.getElementById("name").readOnly = false;
        document.getElementById("number").readOnly = false;
        document.getElementById("status").readOnly = false;
        document.getElementById("expertise").readOnly = false;
        document.getElementById("remark").readOnly = false;
        document.getElementById("edit").style.visibility='hidden';
    }
```

So at first i am able to click on edit button so that my textfields can be edited. once i edited them, i can click on the update button to update those fields in mysql database.

```
    <?php
    $name = $_GET['name'];

    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","test1");
    $output='';
    $sql = "SELECT Name, Number, Expertise, Status, Remarks FROM particulars WHERE Name ='". $name."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

    while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $name = $row['Name'];
    $number =$row['Number'];
    $Expertise =$row['Expertise'];
    $status =$row['Status'];
    $remarks =$row['Remarks'];
} 

    echo "<label>Name</label> <input id = 'name' type='text' value='" .$name. "'/> <br>";
    echo "<label>Number</label><input id = 'number' type='text' value='" .$number. "'/><br>";
    echo "<label>Expertise</label><input id = 'expertise' type='text' value='" .$Expertise. "'/><br>";
    echo "<label>Status</label><input id = 'status' type='text' value='" .$status. "'/><br>";
    echo "<label>Remarks</label><input id = 'remark' type='text' value='" .$remarks. "'/><br>";
    ?>

<br><br><br>
<input type="button" id="edit" value = "Edit" onclick="myfunction()">
<input type="submit" id="update" value = "Update">
```

I would not mind using either a submit button or using ajax to solve this problem. Thank you very much!:)

Comment: Use an `update` sql query.

Comment: @Shadow Yea i know i have to use an update sql query. But im not sure how can i assign those textbox to the sql query statement. do i use $_POST? Sorry i'm quite new to this thing. Thanks for your help!:)

Comment: You do not have a form , so I have no idea how you send the fields' data back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

First a note on your while loop, that passes through all all rows. In your case it should be just one. This works since there is one row only but you should use an approach that shouldn't use a while loop.

Back to your quest. You need a form (simplest way)

```
echo "<form action='mypage.php' method='POST'>"; // Start Form (Forms use names not ids btw)
echo "<label>Name</label> <input name = 'name' type='text' value='" .$name. "'/> <br>";
echo "<label>Number</label><input name = 'number' type='text' value='" .$number. "'/><br>";
echo "<label>Expertise</label><input name = 'expertise' type='text' value='" .$Expertise. "'/><br>";
echo "<label>Status</label><input name = 'status' type='text' value='" .$status. "'/><br>";
echo "<label>Remarks</label><input name = 'remark' type='text' value='" .$remarks. "'/><br>";
echo "<input type='submit' id='update' value = 'Update'>"; // This will send the data
echo "</form>"; // End form
```

mypage.php

```
$sql = "Update particulars  set Number = " .$_POST['number'] etc....
```

It is extremely ineffecient to have Name as a primary key. Numbers are alot easier to process not to mention multiple people can have same names.

Have Id as primary key and set it to auto_increment.

you can add it to your form like this

```
<input name = 'id' type='hidden' value='" .$id. "'/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE particulars SET Name = $name, Number = $number, Expertise = $expertise, Status = $status, Remarks = $remarks WHERE Name = $name;
```

Comment: If I were you, I would use prepared statements to prevent SQL-injection. Try PDO instead mysqli